# Javascript and Regex Store time in Array

Tags: javascript, regex

I want store time in array with regex. Here is what I am using:

```
var re = /\b\d{1,2}:\d{2}\b/g; 
var txt =  '9:50 This is a test with end time in the Clammr 10:10';
var str = txt;
var m;               
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }                   
var starttime = m[0];
var endtime = m[1];
}               
var text = txt.replace(starttime, '');
text = text.replace(endtime, '');
text = jQuery.trim(text);   
console.log('[shortcode text="'+ text +'" start="' + starttime + '" end="' + endtime + '"]');
```

I want this result at the end:

```
[shortcode text="This is an awesome Clammr" start="9:50" end=10:10"]
```

But not sure how, but I am getting this:

```
[shortcode text="9:50 This is a test with end time in the Clammr" start="10:10" end="undefined"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Exec` returns [match,index,string] , so in order to get the match, just use the first index `m[0]` :

Check this snippet.

```js
var re = /\b\d{1,2}:\d{2}\b/g; 
var txt =  '9:50 This is a test with end time in the Clammr 10:10';
var str = txt;
var m;           
var times = [];    
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
 times.push(m[0]);
}               
var text = txt.replace(times[0], '');
text = text.replace(times[1], '');
text = jQuery.trim(text); 

  
$('body').append('[shortcode text="'+ text +'" start="' + times[0] + '" end="' + times[1] + '"]');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `exec`

```
var str = '9:50 This is a test with end time in the Clammr 10:10'

var _time = str.match(/\d{1,2}:\d{2}/g)
var _text = str.replace(/\d{1,2}:\d{2}/g, "").trim()

var _shortCode = '[shortcode text="' + _text + '" start="' + _time[0] + '" end="' + _time[1] + '"]';
```

**Output**

```
[shortcode text="This is a test with end time in the Clammr" start="9:50" end="10:10"]
```

Comment: Thanks for this is really very smart way :)